# Adding in mysql query and order them

Tags: mysql

This is my result table

```
id | username | mark
 1 | saurav   |  12
 2 | sunny    |  10
 3 | saurav   |  21
 4 | saurav   |  25
 5 | sunny    |  19
 6 | john     |  15
```

I want to add the marks of username and order them in descending order like :

```
saurav | 58
sunny  | 29
john   | 15
```

UPDATE: Also I want to get the position of usernames. Like here, sunny has position 2, john has position 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by myself.

```
SELECT username, SUM( mark ) AS sum
FROM result
GROUP BY username
ORDER BY sum DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Group by the column you want to be unique. If you group then all aggregate functions (like `sum()`) apply to each group and not the complete table

```
select username, sum(mark) marks
from your_table
group by username
order by marks DESC
```

Comment: If you have an additional question then ask another one after you researched and could not get it to work. But there are so many example how to do this. Just google *mysql rank*

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    username,
    sum(mark) AS mark
FROM
    your_table
GROUP BY
    username
ORDER BY
    mark DESC
```